# Shell command works in terminal but not during Jenkins build

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build server that runs the following command before each build is completed:

```
sudo make -f nameOfMakeFile.mak
```

When I'm in the terminal and in the appropriate directory, this command works perfectly and produces the desired OUTDIR file. But for some reason when Jenkins runs the same command I get this error:

```
sudo make -f nameOfMakeFile.mak
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ../../ThirdParty/aes/
```

At which point it proceeds to CD into another directory and fails.

Any idea why my terminal command works but Jenkins running the same command does not?

Comment: Where is the `cd ../../ThirdParty/aes/`?

Answer (score 1):

`../../ThirdParty/aes/` is obviously a relative path. You have no idea where Jenkins is starting from when it executes that `cd` command. You will have to make the path global, or have a known starting point for your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jenkins` user probably has no access to `../../ThirdParty/aes/`

Comment: He pre-pended the script with `sudo`, and from the error that appears to have worked, so the `cd` is being executed as root.